# Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: chrome.extension.onRequest content.js has wrong request.name?

Tags: javascript, php

I get the following error when I run my code in chrome:

> Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: chrome.extension.onRequest content.js has wrong request.name?

I have tried to find the error in my script but I can't find it.

**Here is my script..**

```
function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
     document.getElementById("Location").length = 0;
        switch (listindex) {
           case "Albay":
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[0] = new  Option("Please select framework", "");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[1] = new Option("Bacacay", "Bacacay");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[2] = new Option("Camalig", "Camalig");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[3] = new Option("Daraga", "Daraga");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[4] = new Option("Guinobatan", "Guinobatan");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[5] = new Option("Jovellar", "Jovellar");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[6] = new Option("Legazpi City", "Legazpi City");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[7] = new Option("Libon", "Libon");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[8] = new Option("Ligao", "Ligao");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[9] = new Option("Malilipot", "Malilipot");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[10] = new Option("Malinao", "Malinao");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[11] = new Option("Manito", "Manito");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[12] = new Option("Oas", "Oas");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[13] = new Option("Pioduran", "Pioduran");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[14] = new Option("Polangui", "Polangui");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[15] = new Option("Rapu-Rapu", "Rapu-Rapu");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[16] = new Option("Santo Domingo", "Santo Domingo");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[17] = new Option("Tabaco", "Tabaco");
                 document.getElementById("Location").options[18] = new Option("Tiwi", "Tiwi");
                 break;

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.table-bordered').dataTable({
        "scrollY":        "300px", //Scroll vertical
        "scrollX":        "true", //Scroll Horizontal
        "iDisplayLength": 20, //Display 20 records Per Page
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         true //Pagination

        });
    });

$(document).ready(function()
        {
        $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#E2EFBF");
        });

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.login-window').click(function() {

         var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

         $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

         $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
         $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

$('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
        $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
            $('#mask').remove();  
        }); 
        return false;
        });
        }); 

    function pop_up(url){
        window.open(
                    url,
                    'win2',
                    'status=no,
                    toolbar=no,
                    scrollbars=yes,
                    titlebar=no,
                    menubar=no,
                    resizable=yes,
                    width=800,
                    height=600,
                    directories=no,
                    location=no'
         ) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the chrome browser and try to download the other version of it. I meet the same problem with you when i check my website: http://quanglepro.com/2016/05/31/yoast-seo-plugin-premium/

But i have 2 laptop, I do the same step on 2 laptop
The first laptop is OK with chrome
The second is look the same issue with you.

Could you check on other PC or try to remove and install another chrome source
you can test with my website: http://quanglepro.com/2016/05/31/yoast-seo-plugin-premium/

Thank you
Quangle